# filtering date in two diffrent primeng tables by using one filter

Tags: angular, filter, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-calendar

I have an issue in implementing an idea using date filter in primeng table
i have two tables each one has a date filter
the idea i want to implement is using a date filter to filter both tables at the same time

Thanks

Comment: Prime-ng has a `FilterService`. Look at this. Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mmzi8y-peatrj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't implement the same idea